# Facing Issue in returning update obj from promise resolve - Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, es6-promise

I have below parser.js file in lib/rrpair/parser.js. I have a parse function  where I am iterating through different files in a directory and preparing a service object from their contents.

```
const dir = require('node-dir');

function parse(path) {
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
      const serv = new Service();
      dir.readFiles(path, function (err, content, filename, next) {
          //getting files content & preparing/updating service object
          next();
        });
    //returning serv object
    return resolve(serv); 
  });
}
```

I am calling the above parse function from below Controllers/serviceController.js

```
 const rrpair = require('../lib/rrpair/parser');

function createService(req, res) {
  rrpair.parse('./RRPair' ).then(function(message){
    console.log(message);
    res.json(message);
  }).catch(function(err){
    console.log(err);
  });
}
```

problem :- I am getting blank service object returned from parser function. I debugged it and found that dir.readFiles() function in parser.js executes but later after returning service object. So parser function returning new Service() object but not the updated object which is updated in dir.readFiles() function.

while debugging I found when control goes to dir.readFiles(.. line if i press F10(step over) than control directly go to return resolve(serv); line. and it return new service object with out updating it. Later control again comes back inside dir.readFiles(..   function. but no use of executing this now as I 
 have already got the new blank service object. I am not able to solve/understand this through debugging. I am newbie in Nodejs. Please help

Answer (score 0):

You need to `resolve` *inside* the callback, after `next` populates the service (else, if you call `resolve` *outside* the callback, *synchronously*, there wouldn't be much point using a `Promise` in the first place, because no asynchronous operations have had a chance to do their work yet).

You should also consider *rejecting* the `Promise` when there's an `err`, rather than ignoring errors - otherwise, the error won't be caught by the `catch` in `createService`:

```
function parse(path) {
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    const serv = new Service();
    dir.readFiles(path, function (err, content, filename, next) {
      if (err) return reject(err);
      //getting files content & preparing/updating service object
      next();
      resolve(serv); 
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: I tried this. but this way I am not getting response back. Http status is pending. i.e;   I think request is stuck because it's waiting for resolve(serv).  It responded after 1 minute but it didn't solve my problem. I will test more

Comment: Note that your current code does not respond with anything if there's an error - it only `console.log`s it. Try `res.json`ing an error inside the `catch`